# Using bat script to write text file: missing character

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2008-r2

I am using a bat script to attempt to write several lines to a text file. However, in one case, a character is being dropped that I wish to write.

Here is the code:

```
@echo off
@echo san policy=onlineall> test.txt
@echo select disk 1>> test.txt
@echo online disk>> test.txt
```

Here is the resulting text file (test.txt)

```
san policy=onlineall
select disk 
online disk
```

Why is the "1" missing from the resulting code?

Comment: You can redirect specifc output chanels. 1 is standard output and 2 is standard error (test.txt would contain the error message if an error occurs). So that script interprets the `1` as the specification which output chanel you like to redirect. Can you try `@echo "select disk 1">> test.txt`?

Comment: Thanks Tom. When I try putting that in quotes, it outputs "select disk 1" in test.txt, that is, the file has quotes around that line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escaping the `1` with a caret would also work:

```
@echo off
@echo san policy=onlineall> test.txt
@echo select disk ^1>> test.txt
@echo online disk>> test.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

You can redirect different streams with `>`. They are distinguished via numbers, 0 is stdin, 1 is stdout, 2 is stderr, to list the predefined ones.

So to answer your question, when you write `1>`, windows thinks you want to echo to stream 1 (which is the default anyway). A possible solution is to simply insert a space between, but that will output this space, too. But, you can also write it like this:

```
>>test.txt echo select disk 1
```

Comment: That works great. In my case, also adding the space does not affect the program that the file will be read by (DISKPART), so both solutions work.